# Why Timestamp type is not nullable in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server

I have used following command..

```
select * 
from sys.types 
where is_user_defined = 0
```

Here `timestamp` datatype is not nullable. I googled and not satisfied why it is?

Is it possible to conditionally avoid my timestamp column updatation..........

Comment: It is automatically updated by the system on every insert or update operation so why would it be nullable?

Comment: `Timestamp` is a synonym for `rowversion` in SQL Server and you can read about it [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182776.aspx)

Comment: @MartinSmith Sir can it is possible to conditionally avoid my timestamp column pdatation..........

Comment: @Abhishekpandey - No. It is always updated to `@@DBTS` on every insert or update. It can never be null.

Comment: Do you really need timestamp? It is not used for 'custom' row timestamping; mabe you would benefit from using datetime/datetime2?

Comment: @MartinSmith Sir i have a scenario where if admin update some record then timestamp column does not changed otherwise it will updated.. can I achieve this.....

Comment: Sounds like you need some sort of `datetime` datatype. Then you control when you want it updated.

Comment: @Abhishekpandey: This could be a nice question...

Comment: Then use a string to store the timestamp and provide the value from your buisness layer